# In Ember, how would one prevent an action that belongs to an encompassing element?

Tags: ember.js

I'm using Ember, and I have a box that the user can click and it will pop open a modal window with more info.

I also have a button on that box that performs a different action.

If I click on the button, the correct action is triggered, but it also triggers the action for the encompassing `<div>`.  How do I prevent that action on the `<div>`, while allowing the action from the `<button>`?

Here's my template:

```
<div {{action 'openModal' 'productResultOverview' this}} class="simpleproducttile">
    <div class="row simpleproducttitle">
        <p>{{ProductId}}<i class="icon-export helpiconleft"></i><img src="img/largebox.png"></img></p>
    </div>
    <div class="row simpleproductdescription">
        <p>{{ProductDescription}}</p>
    </div>
    <div class="medium primary btn customizebutton">
        <input type="submit" {{action "sendToSavedItems"}} value="Select and Customize"/>
    </div>
</div>
```

---

Edit:

Action for the button:

```
App.ProductResultController = Ember.ObjectController.extend({
    actions: {
        sendToSavedItems: function() {
            console.log('sending to saved items');
        }
    }
});
```

And the action `openModal` is contained within `ApplicationRoute`:

```
App.ApplicationRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
    id: 'modal',
    actions: {
        openModal: function (modalName, model) {
            console.log('opening modal', modalName, model);
            return this.render(modalName, {
                into: 'application',
                outlet: 'modal',
                model: model
            });
        },
//....
});
```

Comment: Can you add the controller code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [Ember.js docs](http://emberjs.com/guides/templates/actions/):

> By default, the `{{action}}` helper allows events it handles to bubble up to parent DOM nodes. If you want to stop propagation, you can disable propagation to the parent node.

What you should do is add `bubbles=false` to the inner items:

```
<input type="submit" {{action "sendToSavedItems" bubbles=false}} value="Select and Customize"/>
```

This should stop the click from propagating to the parent `<div>`.

Comment: Ah!  Wonderful, that's precisely it.  I had missed a few words when I looked over it, thinking that the bubbling was referring to: `View -> Controller -> Route`-type bubbling.  Thank you.

Comment: Yes, it's easy to confuse the two, as conceptually they are similar. :) (Don't forget to mark as answered when you're able to. :))